# Is there any way to handle big responses in Graphql (Appsync)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm currently utilizing GraphQL in AWS AppSync to send requests to AWS Lambda. We're managing a substantial amount of data and encountering an issue concerning the response.

When I execute the lambda independently, I receive an "OK" response. However, when I employ GraphQL to invoke the lambda, I encounter the following error: "Transformation too large". I suspect the problem is associated with the size of the response, as mentioned earlier, it appears to be excessively large. When I use GraphQL for smaller amounts of data, everything works perfectly fine.

Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!